# The visual studio conversion wizard launched when i try to open solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a visual studio solution created on a x64 machine with VS 2010
When i try to open the same solution with the same version of VS 2010 in an other machine (x86), the visual studio conversion wizard is launched
why the converter is launched dispite the fact that i have the same version of VS 2010 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the upgrade and then look at the log file to see what changed.  Also compare the changed files to the originals.  That may give you hints as to what else might be different.  I had a similar problem and found that I needed to install Service Pack 1 of Visual Studio 2010.